# Share single instance between classes in Kotlin

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-plugin

I'm working with a 3rd party SDK in a Flutter plugin (Kotlin), and need to instantiate a particular class once, so I can share the state with various different instances of Method- and Event Channels.

I have several classes that expose 'features' as event channels, and they all use the same instance of a callback from the SDK.

For visual reference:

```kotlin
com.company.example
-- Feature1StreamHandler
-- Feature2StreamHandler
-- Feature3MethodHandler
-- Featuer4MethodHandler
```

Each one of these handler implementations, require a `scan` instance, which needs to be configured once, when the application starts up and then dispose of it, when the application closes.

Coming from C#, I'd implement a contract, create a concrete implementation and initialise the class during the application bootstrap stage, startup, however, a similar 'pattern' in Android does not seem to work, as I kind of expect the bootstrap to be the MainActivity, however, data is then not passed on to the Flutter plugin portion.

I'm hoping my explanation makes sense...

Something like this:

In MainActivity, construct `SDKScan` object.

In the Flutter plugin, for argument sake, MyPlugin, I want that instance of SDKScan created in MainActivity.

Comment: This will depend on the platform. In plain Kotlin, you could simply create an `object` holding the reference. In Spring, you could create a `@Component` holding the reference. But I don't know about Android (which I guess is what you're asking about).

Comment: @gidds yeah, for now I went object, seem to work well in this scenario